# Ошибка - TypeError: data.filter is not a function, телеграм бот

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Вообщем, написал бота, но он при нажатии кнопки выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: data.filter is not a function
    at Request._callback (D:\Programming\Web\telegram-bot\index.js:38:27)
    at Request.self.callback (D:\Programming\Web\telegram-bot\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\Web\telegram-bot\node_modules\request\request.js:1157:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\Web\telegram-bot\node_modules\request\request.js:1079:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1090:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Вот код бота (там где ошибка), объясните почему так происходит, пожалуйста:

```
bot.onText(/\/course/, (msg, match) => {
    var chatId = msg.chat.id;
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Choose the currency you are interested in:', {
        reply_markup: {
          inline_keyboard: [
            [
              {
                text: '$ - USD',
                callback_data: 'USD'
              },
              {
                text: '€ - EUR',
                callback_data: 'EUR'
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
    });
});

bot.on('callback_query', query => {
    var id = query.message.chat.id;
    request('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js', function(error, response, body) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        // filter body and take only item ccy.
        var result = data.filter(item => item.CharCode === query.data)[0];
            let md = `
            *${result.CharCode} => ${result.Name}*
            Buy: _${result.Value}_
            `;
        bot.sendMessage(id, md, {parse_mode:'Markdown'});
    })
});
```

Если есть ошибки в том, откуда я брал [курc валюты](https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js), укажите, буду признателен.

Answer (score 3):

`body` передаваемый в `JSON.parse(body)` это json *объекта*, поэтому при его разборе получается массив, а не объект, а у объектов нет метода `filter`.

Судя по возвращаемому объекту, нужно было использовать свойство `Valute`

```
var result = data.Valute.filter
```

Однако это тоже не сработает, так как `Valute` - это тоже объект, а не массив, поэтому проходить по нему нужно с помощью других средств, например с помощью цикла [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), либо получение массива значений [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```
var result = Object.values(data.Valute).filter(...)
```

Comment: ошибка сохранилась

Comment: @Masson, логично, потому что `Valute` - Тот же объект.

Comment: спасибо, заработало!